# Applying a condition to a df to get the aggregate counts

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have this df structured like this, where each year has the same rows/entries:

```
Year    Name    Expire

2001    Bob     2002
2001    Tim     2003
2001    Will    2004
2002    Bob     2002
2002    Tim     2003
2002    Will    2004
2003    Bob     2002
2003    Tim     2003
2003    Will    2004
```

I have subsetted the df (df[df['Expire']> df['Year'])

```
2001    Bob     2002
2001    Tim     2003
2001    Will    2004
2002    Tim     2003
2002    Will    2004
2003    Will    2004
```

Now I want to return the count for each year the amount of names that expired, something like:

```
Year    count
2001     0
2002     1
2003     1
```

How can I accomplish this? I can't do (df[df['Expire']<= df['Year'])['name'].groupby('Year').agg(['count']), because that would return unnecessary rows for me. Any way to count only the last instance only?

Comment: isn't `df.groupby(['Expire'])['Name'].count()` what you need?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with boolean mask and aggregate `sum`:

```
print (df['Expire']<= df['Year'])
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
8    False
dtype: bool

df=(df['Expire']<=df['Year']).groupby(df['Year']).sum().astype(int).reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
   Year  count
0  2001      0
1  2002      1
2  2003      2
```

Verifying:

```
print (df[df['Expire']<= df['Year']])
   Year Name  Expire
3  2002  Bob    2002
6  2003  Bob    2002
7  2003  Tim    2003
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC : You can use `.apply` and `sum` of true values i.e

```
df.groupby('Year').apply(lambda x: (x['Expire']<=x['Year']).sum())
```

Output:

```
Year
2001    0
2002    1
2003    2
```